# HTML Data shown as text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a HTML page that will display some data sent by another application and the other application sends data only in `text` format and this is the reason in my HTML the `<` is being rendered as `&lt;`, `>` as `&rt;` and so on...

In my `HTML` I need to create a div and place this entire content inside that `div`.

Below is my Javascript.

```
function showResponse(lexResponse) {
    var conversationDiv = document.getElementById('conversation');
    var responsePara = document.createElement("P");
    responsePara.className = 'lexResponse';
    if (lexResponse.message) {
        createOrUpdateCompositeLink(lexResponse.message, responsePara);
    }
    conversationDiv.appendChild(responsePara);
    conversationDiv.scrollTop = conversationDiv.scrollHeight;
}

function createOrUpdateCompositeLink(input, ref) {
    if (ref) {
        if (input.match(/href/g)) {
            var isLinkText = input.match(/href/g);
            var elementChild;
            if (isLinkText) {
                elementChild = document.createElement('span');
                elementChild.innerHTML = input;
            } else {
                elementChild = document.createTextNode(input);
            }
            ref.appendChild(elementChild);
            return ref;
        } else {
            console.log("Entered Blocl");
            var elementChild;
            elementChild = document.createElement('div');
            elementChild.innerHTML = convertHTML(input);
            ref.appendChild(elementChild);
            return ref;
        }
    } else {
        var element = document.createElement('p');
        element.innerHTML = input;
        return element;
    }
}

function convertHTML(str) {
    var entityPairs = [
        { character: '&', html: '&amp;' },
        { character: '<', html: '&lt;' },
        { character: '>', html: '&gt;' },
        { character: "'", html: '&apos;' },
        { character: '"', html: '&quot;' },
    ];

    entityPairs.forEach(function (pair) {
        var reg = new RegExp(pair.character, 'g');
            str = str.replace(reg, pair.html);
    });
    return str;
}
```

Here I get my input in `lexResponse.message` and I need to render it, when I do a `console.log` I get the output as

```
Sure. I can assist you with you that, do you have any preference with 'Date' criteria? You can say something like "before/ after Oct 20th 2017" or "since July 1st 2017". <select><option value="since">Since</option><option value="before">Before</option></select> <input type="date" />
```

please let me know how I can render the data to display in HTML.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `convertHTML(input)`?

Comment: @AlecFenichel to parse the data...in my output I'm getting &lt; type things, thought this function would be helpful. But unfortunately it isn't :-(

Comment: `convertHTML` is converting `<` to `&lt;`. But you want `<`, so I don't understand why you are using `convertHTML`?

Comment: @AlecFenichel my bad, I think I'm using it the other way...thanks for the quick poke

Comment: Use `elementChild.innerHTML = input;` instead of `elementChild.innerHTML = convertHTML(input);`;

Comment: @AlecFenichel even that's printing &lt;. The data returned is in text format

Comment: I guess the conversion is done on the server side already (e.g. htmlspecialchars) Are you dealing with data received via http?

Comment: @Psi yes, you are absolutely perfect.

Comment: Glad I could help